# Converting Spatial Text to Spatial Column

Tags: mysql, polygon, spatial

Just started to play around with mysql spatial:

```
ID       BDY

4BCTD   152.936368,-27.22613|152.936525,-27.226409|152.937087,-27.228033|152.937327,-....
```

I have a BDY table which consists of ID and BDY.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_geom 
(ID VARCHAR(4),
BDY text,
GEOLOC GEOMETRY);
```

BDY have the latitude, longitude text and I would liek to convert teh boundary into a spatial column called GEOLOC.

Tried this but didn't work:

```
UPDATE  tbl_geom b SET  GEOLOC = POLYFROMTEXT('SELECT  bdy  FROM tbl_geom a');
```

Kept returning null

Even These queries returning null

```
SELECT GeomFromText('SELECT  bdy  FROM tbl_geom a');

SELECT polyFromText('SELECT  bdy  FROM tbl_geom a');

SELECT AsText(bdy) FROM tbl_geom;
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query should be

```
UPDATE `tbl_geom` SET `GEOLOC` = POLYFROMTEXT(CONCAT('POLYGON((', REPLACE(REPLACE(`bdy`, ',', ' '), '|', ','), '))'));
```

This:

- converts the commas to spaces in bdy
- converts the pipes to commas
- tops and tails it in a POLYGON call
- updates GEOLOC